# Azure app service multi container - http request to internal container (docker compose)

Tags: c#, azure, docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I have deployed a multicontainer app service in Azure using a docker compose file (preview).

The webapplication exposes port 80, so if I go to https://myproj.azurewebsites.net/ the webapplication is displayed, (it's the only public port available).

What I would like to do now is to be able to send a http request from the web to my api which is another container hosted internally. I've tried different urls but I'm unable to make a successful request. 
The api container starts successfully so there is nothing wrong there, I just dont know which address to use.

**OrderApi Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyProj.OrderApi/MyProj.OrderApi.csproj", "MyProj.OrderApi/"]
COPY ["nuget.config", "MyProj.OrderApi/"]
RUN dotnet restore "v.OrderApi/MyProj.OrderApi.csproj" --configfile "MyProj.OrderApi/nuget.config"
RUN rm "MyProj.OrderApi/nuget.config"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MyProj.OrderApi"
RUN dotnet build "MyProj.OrderApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProj.OrderApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProj.OrderApi.dll"]
```

**Docker compose file used in production (Azure)**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
web:
    image: myproj.azurecr.io/myproj/web
    ports:
    - '80:80'

orderapi:
    image: myproj.azurecr.io/myproj/orderapi
```

**Endpoints tested**

https://localhost/orderapi/api - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

http://localhost/orderapi/api - blocked by CORS policy (I'm certain cors is configured correctly in the api)

https://host.docker.internal/orderapi/api - ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

orderapi/api - Adds current site as baseurl.. tries to send a request to 
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/orderapi/api

http://host.docker.internal/orderapi/api - This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

host.docker.internal/orderapi/api - Adds current site as baseurl.. Tries to send a request to 
https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/host.docker.internal/orderapi/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Azure Web App for Container only can expose one container to the Internet. It means if you deploy multiple containers in the Web App, you can only access one container from the Internet. See the details about **How do I know which container is internet accessible** in [Multi-container with Docker Compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-faq#multi-container-with-docker-compose).

Update:

When you set the service like this in your docker-compose file:

```
redis:
  image: redis
  container_name: rediscache
```

Then here is the example in code to connect the container redis:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class NewsController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get()
    {
        ConnectionMultiplexer connection = await ConnectionMultiplexer.ConnectAsync("redis");
        var db = connection.GetDatabase();

        //code to parse the XML
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes i know this! But can the web application not access the internal network, the api and the web is hosted together so should work? Or maybe the javascript is called outside the network?

Comment: @Reft The containers inside the same Web App can connect to each other through the name of the service you set in the docker-compose file. You can take a look at [How to deploy multiple container application on web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/appconsult/deploy-a-docker-multi-container-application-on-azure-web-apps).

Comment: Yes but that is from the serverside. What I want is to send a http request from the web application to the internal api. They are both in the same app service but my guess is that the javascript http request is fired from outside of the internal network...

Comment: @Reft What do you mean? As I see both your web and API are in the same docker-compose file, it means there are in the same web app and the same host. Just like a front end and the database so that the front end must can access the database. Like the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app). So why not they can communicate each other?

Comment: Yes so then this should be possible. Im exposing port in dockerfile and defining correct ports in the compose file but im still not able to send an http request from the web to the api. You can see which urls i've tested in my question

Comment: @Reft I think you do not look at the link I provided you carefully. See the update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose file, the orderapi doesn´t exposes any port. If no exposes any port,  there is not way it could  process requests.

Usually, the browser gets the html and sends  the request directly to the API.

Maybe orderapi should expose other port (for example 88) so the browser can consume data from the API using this port.

Comment: Iv'e added expose 88 in dockerfile, -p 88 in compose file and tested with http://localhost:88/api/ but im still getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: In dockerfile you can use port 80 (EXPOSE 80) but in the docker-compose.yml file for the orderapi service, expose port 88 of host to port 80 of container (    ports:
        - "88:80" ) , after the container is running list the ports exposed with "docker ps" or "docker-compose ps"